# Бывают ли случаи, когда for нельзя заменить while-ом?

Tags: циклы, любой-язык

p.s. Примеры писать на java или js.

Comment: Никогда не задумывались об этом?

    int max = 5;
    int c = 0;
    for(;c < max;){
       c++;
       printf("c = %d\n",c);
    }

Comment: А это обратная ситуация: замена while for'ом. )))

Comment: только наверно `c++;` после принта

Comment: Ну, это смотря, что ему нужно

Comment: c++; - :D!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for` - это частный случай `while`, который в свою очередь является частным случаем `goto`. Так что ответ - нет. Хотя если поставить вопрос наоборот: "Бывают ли случаи, когда while нельзя заменить for-ом?", то ответ скорее всего тоже будет нет, следовательно все циклы с предусловаем эквивалентны

---

Ах да, есть случаи: когда у команды такой code style, который **обязательно** требует использования `for` в случае любых циклов

Comment: while(check) == for (;check;)

Comment: Ах да, есть случаи: когда у команды такой code style, который обязательно требует использования for в случае любых циклов

Вы сами встречали такие случая? o_O

Comment: я допускаю вероятность существования такого случая

Comment: Это уже вопрос вне проблем программирования как такового.

Comment: Высший пилотаж это полная замена while, for, if и switch шаблонами

Comment: @igumnov, а продемонстрировать можете?

Comment: @igumnov, это Вы метапрограммирование имеете в виду?

Comment: @igumnov, а как сильно надо накуриться, чтобы до такого додуматься? Примеры в студию.

Comment: Ага, а goto - частный случай единичек и нулей =)

     for - это частный случай while, который в свою очередь является частным случаем goto

Answer (score 6):

Думаю, что нет. Есть даже языки, в которых нет эквивалента for, только while (например, Python). И ничего, вполне успешны.

Comment: Соглашусь, не видел ситуаций, когда цикл `for` нельзя переписать как цикл `while` + доп. инструкции.

Comment: Даже логический анализ работы for показывает, что его вполне можно заменить. Предусловие, условие новой итерации, действие после каждой итерации - все это вполне можно сделать в while. for - просто более удобная запись.

Comment: Не совсем. Я бы вспомнил существование конструкции `for-each`, но ее в целом тоже можно свести к `while`

Comment: for_each - это немного другое. Это итерация по элементам коллекции.

Answer (score 0):

Да бывают, когда надо в for за пихнуть например, 3 while.
Вот например такая задача:
Дружественными числами называются два различных натуральных числа, для которых сумма всех собственных делителей первого числа (сумма всех делителей, отличных от самого числа) равна второму числу и сумма всех собственных делителей второго числа равна первому числу.
 Примеры дружественных чисел: 220 и 284. Делители числа 220: 1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 11, 20, 22, 44, 55, 110 (в сумме дают число 284); делители числа 284: 1, 2, 4, 71, 142 (в сумме 220).
 Примеры других пар дружественных чисел: 2620 и 2924, 17296 и 18416.
 Написать программу, которая по заданному натуральному числу N находит все пары дружественных чисел, не превосходящих N.
Попробуй реши ее без for. Лично у меня не получилось.

Comment: Решать неохота. Нельзя ли привести решение с for? Тогда можно было бы перевести в вариант с while.

Comment: Ну на скорую руку с циклом for, хоть и корявенько, но решил таким образом: http://govnokod.ru/12067

Comment: Ну и почему это в while не переводится ?

    ....
    i = 0;
    while (i <= x) {
      s = 0;
      y = 1;
      while (y < i) {
        if (i % y == 0) { s += y; }
        y++;
      }
      t = 0;
      y = 1;
      while (y < s) {
        if (s % y == 0) { t += y; }
        y++;
      }
      if(t == i && s != i && !friends_nums.containsValue(i)) { friends_nums.put(i, s); }
      i++;
    }
    .....

IMHO то же самое, что и 

    for(int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
      int s = 0;
      for(int y = 1; y < i; y++) {
        if(i % y == 0) { s += y; }
      }
      int t = 0;
      for( ...